getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running android application
I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running android application. I tried to debug using stacktrace but no use.
Getting this error
2024-07-01 12:19:28.157 AndroidRuntime           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.ashishdake.imdbulletinandsatelliteimages, PID: 28962
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at in.ashishdake.imdbulletinandsatelliteimages.Activities.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomeActivity.java:108)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4292)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ComponentActivity.java:520)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:95)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3429)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:458)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:58)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)

This is where we are calling public static function
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

        try {
            if (AppConstants.unreadNotificationCount() > 0) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.actionNotifications).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24);
            } else {
                menu.findItem(R.id.actionNotifications).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24);
            }
        }
        catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {
            for(int i=0;i<e.getStackTrace().length;i++){
                Log.e("ExceptionInInitializer", e.getStackTrace()[i].toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

This is public class
public static int unreadNotificationCount() {
        DatabaseCreation dbCreation = new DatabaseCreation(ImdBulletinAndSatteliteImages.getAppContext(), db_name, null, db_version);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbCreation.getWritableDatabase();

        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbTblNotification + " WHERE " + dbTblNotificationStatus + "='0'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }

This is stack trace
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  in.ashishdake.imdbulletinandsatelliteimages.Utils.AppConstants.unreadNotificationCount(AppConstants.java:226)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  in.ashishdake.imdbulletinandsatelliteimages.Activities.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomeActivity.java:110)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4292)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ComponentActivity.java:520)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:95)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3429)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:458)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.630 ExceptionInInitializer   E  androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:58)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8315)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
2024-07-01 20:38:25.631 ExceptionInInitializer   E  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)


The problem is in a class initialization ... not the method that you are calling; see https://www.baeldung.com/java-exceptionininitializererror . There should be a stacktrace for the exception that triggered this problem.

I have edited question and added stacktrace.
